# Silverlight ASP.MVC routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, routes

how can I emulate stuff like <%=Url.Action("Action","Controller" ...
where I am using Silverlight 4 as the client to ASP.MVC in say OpenReadAsync?
Aside from passing it a Uri with the full path as a string - not preferred.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Those are two different applications and the Silverlight application knows nothing about the routes you could have set in your ASP.NET MVC application.